# How do I setup an android tablet for dedicated use and distribution to end users?

Tags: android, tablet

I would like to setup android tablets that are dedicated to using one specific app and would be distributed to end users.  I asked the app supplier if they have the .apk available for direct download; they said yes, but they do not recommend this approach because the app is updated frequently and this approach would rely to some extent on end users performing some manual steps to update the app (it probably would not get done timely or not at all in some cases) whereas if the app is obtained via Play store, updates are accomplished more automatically.  However, for the Play store approach, a Google account is required.  Creating a dummy Google account for each tablet does not seem like a good approach and creating one dummy Google account for all of these tablets also seems like a bad idea (the devices might all synch/share some resources across all of these tablets for end users who do not know each other and should not be sharing anything with each other).  Is there another approach to this scenario that would better achieve the goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume you have a web server to serve your "latest app" you can ask your developer to make a simple version check, download the update apk, and kick start the installation as below:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(PATH, "update.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // without this flag
                                                        // android returned
                                                        // a intent error!
        context.startActivity(intent);
```